# App Store Review: my app requires a UK IP address

Tags: ios, ip-address

I have an iOS app that will only work with a UK IP address - therefore apple will not be able to review it correctly. How do people handle this type of problem when it comes to the review process?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Comment: By UK IP address, you must mean an IPv4 address (IPv6 is not prevalent here yet). Apple will not budge on this rule.
As @djromero says, get a VPN with IPv6 and shunt the traffic to your IPv4 server here in the UK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's possible, remove the limitation until it's approved. You can do it if you control the server or in the app itself downloading a small configuration file with restrictions, etc. before the actual connection stuff starts.

If not, provide them with a proxy with a UK IP address. You can set it up yourself or just get a 1 month (or so) service in a VPN provider. And add the corresponding instructions in iTunes Connect to configure the iPhone proxy (just in case).